# IF ROW_COUNT() return error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

According to this article ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx ) 
I would like to do something like this:

```
UPDATE chunks SET targets = CONCAT(targets, ",phpValue1") 
    WHERE scopeX=phpValue2 AND scopeY=phpValue3;

IF ROW_COUNT() = 0
    INSERT INTO chunks (scopeX, scopeY, targets) VALUES (phpValue2,phpValue3,phpValue1)
```

But then I receive this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 
>                           INSERT INTO chunks (scopeX, scopeY, targets)

I also tried with "THEN" after the condition but it didn't work either.
What also might be interesting is that I am working with the newest Version of XAMPP, I think, which still uses MySQL 5.0, when I looked it up correctly.

for sure phpValue* is inserted by php correctly
thank you very much for any help =)

Comment: Are you running this through PHP? If so, are you by any chance using `mysql_query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use control statements like `if` without a function around it. You have to put that in a function, procedure, trigger or event.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing Microsoft articles about MS SQL, but you're using MySQL. They're different languages that work different ways, despite their similarities.

That sort of IF statement won't work in MySQL, but may well work in MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
$query = mysql_query ("select * from ...........");
$count = mysql_affected_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you will need to do this in a stored procedure. Here is the basic structure for FOUND_ROWS() and IF....

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE PROCEDURE `testproc`()    
 BEGIN

 SET @INS = "SELECT * FROM  yourschema.yourtable;";
 PREPARE STMT FROM @INS;
 EXECUTE STMT;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;

 SET @i = FOUND_ROWS();

 IF(@i > 0) THEN SELECT 1; 
 END IF;

 END $$

 DELIMITER ;
```